# Subfield manipulation with JS (Laravel Backpack)

Tags: javascript, laravel-backpack

according to the docs:
crud.field('testimonials').subfield('text') -> returns the CrudField for the text subfield within the testimonials repeatable field;

I have this js widget:

```
crud.field('movement').onChange(function(field) {
    if (field.value == 'receive') {
        crud.field('document').show()
        crud.field('laundryItems').subfield('qty').hide();
    } else {
        crud.field('document').hide()
        crud.field('laundryItems').subfield('qty').show();
    }
}).change();
```

When I change the movement field value to 'receive' the button for the repeteable LaundryItems is hiding. How can I hide the subfield instead?

[image]

Comment: Hey Angel, can you post a screenshot of what is hiding ? I didn't get "the button for the repeteable LaundryItems is hiding".

Cheers

Comment: Hi Pedro, I just edited the question to add the image.

Comment: Hi @PedroX Any news about that? Thanks in advance